# My collegaue shared a zip file using a git repository and I can't see the extracted files in GitHub. What commands should I use?

Tags: git, gitlab

I first cloned the repository which had the zip file and then extracted it in the same location.I deleted the zip file.After that, I tried to commit the changes from the local branch to remote branch and when I give

```
 git status
```

I can see that I have deleted the zip file but the extracted file is nowhere to be seen.
I cannot see the files in GitHub too.
What should I do?

Comment: Clone it again and see if the zip file has contents or if it is empty. Also can you add what is the log of git status?

Comment: What does the zip contain? What does the repo contain? What does the directory contain after you unzip the file? Isn't the file extracted but in a .gitignore file? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

If git status shows the zip file deleted, that means you can restore it:

```
git restore -- afile.zip
```

From there you can extract it again, and make a new `git status` to understand how those extracted files are interpreted by your current repository.